# How to only store the index，not the original text in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search 7.10.1. I would store and search against my blogs. The blog has id,title and content fields.

I would like to search against id, title and content, but since the content of blog is too big, so that I would like to save the original content text outside of Elastic Search, such as HBase.

I would ask how to achieve this in ES?

Comment: some part of your question was not clear to me, like  what do you mean by `store the id, title but also the index in ES`  and again `save the index only and save the blog text itself in other places`?

Comment: I added an answer with-params that controls the indexing(tokens used for searching) and store(to retrieve the original value) but if you have follow-up questions please let me know.

Comment: Also, what i got is that you just want to search on `large content field` but don't want to store its original value??

Comment: Thanks @opster-elasticsearch-ninja for the reply. Yes, I mean that I want to search against content,but not to store the original value in ES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a static mapping then simply don't define your `content` field in your index mapping, and don't populate it while indexing your document to ES.

Refer to [Mapping param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-params.html) for more info, and specifically, [store param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) default `false` which means you can't retrieve field value if _source(true by default) is also disabled.

[index param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) default true, which controls whether the field is searchable or not, in your case if you don't want to search and retrieve it you have to disable these two params.